# Combining 2 Tables with an OUTER JOIN on Another Table

Tags: mysql, join, outer-join

I need to combine 2 tables that may or may not have the data in them, but than I need a full outer join where the last table (if has content where IsActive = 1) gets shown that data, instead of the combined first 2 tables.

Currently have this:

```
( SELECT    qp.ItemName AS name
          , qp.TimeAdded AS created
          , '' AS effective
          , qp.VendorName AS supplier
          , qp.Source AS source
          , qp.VendorType AS type
          , qp.Price AS cost
          , '' AS price
          , '' AS markup
          , '' AS customer
          , '' AS customerListID
          , qp.VendorListID AS vendorListID
          , '' AS itemListID
  FROM      wp_quantum_purchases AS qp
  WHERE     qp.IsActive = 1 AND
            NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                         FROM   wp_hunter_quote_parts AS hqp
                         WHERE  qp.ItemName = hqp.ItemName AND
                                hqp.IsActive = 1 ))
UNION ALL
( SELECT    qs.ItemName AS name
          , qs.TimeAdded AS created
          , qs.SalesDate AS effective
          , '' AS supplier
          , qs.Source AS source
          , '' AS type
          , '' AS cost
          , qs.Price AS price
          , '' AS markup
          , qs.CustomerName AS customer
          , qs.CustomerListID AS customerListID
          , '' AS vendorListID
          , '' AS itemListID
  FROM      wp_quantum_sales AS qs
  WHERE     qs.IsActive = 1 AND
            NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                         FROM   wp_hunter_quote_parts AS hqp
                         WHERE  qs.ItemName = hqp.ItemName AND
                                hqp.IsActive = 1 ))
UNION ALL
( SELECT    hqp.ItemName AS name
          , hq.Quote_Date AS created
          , hqp.SalesDate AS effective
          , hqp.VendorName AS supplier
          , hqp.Source AS source
          , hqp.VendorType AS type
          , hqp.Cost AS cost
          , hqp.Price AS price
          , CAST(( ( ( CAST(hqp.Price AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) - CAST(hqp.Cost AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) ) / CAST(hqp.Cost AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) ) * 100 ) AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS markup
          , IFNULL(hq.Customer_FullName, 'N/A') AS customer
          , hq.Customer_ListID AS customerListID
          , hqp.VendorListID AS vendorListID
          , hqp.Item_ListID AS itemListID
  FROM      wp_hunter_quote_parts AS hqp
  LEFT JOIN wp_hunter_quotes AS hq
  ON        ( hq.id = hqp.QuoteID )
  WHERE     hqp.IsActive = 1)
ORDER BY NAME ASC;
```

But this is duplicating the data in 1st and 2nd tables and shows the data twice.  I need the data from 1st and 2nd tables to be combined as 1 (if exists), but to prioritize the last table (`wp_hunter_quote_parts`) in here as the content to show from, if `IsActive = 1` exists in the last table (`wp_hunter_quote_parts`).  However, if `IsActive = 1` does not exist in `wp_hunter_quote_parts` for `ItemName` than I would like to combine both `wp_quantum_purchases` and `wp_quantum_sales` as if it were 1 row.

Can not do a `LEFT JOIN` since data could exist in `wp_quantum_purchases`, but not in `wp_quantum_sales` OR data could exist in `wp_quantum_sales` and not in `wp_quantum_purchases`, OR data could not exist in either of these, and only exist in `wp_hunter_quote_parts` as well as data might not even exist in `wp_hunter_quote_parts`.

So, basically, if ItemName exists in `wp_quantum_purchases` AND IsActive = 1 AND `wp_hunter_quote_parts` does not have ItemName in table, get purchase data from `wp_quantum_purchases`, else if ItemName exists in `wp_hunter_quote_parts` get data from `hunter_quote_parts` instead.

If ItemName exists in `wp_quantum_sales` AND IsActive = 1 AND `wp_hunter_quote_parts` does not have ItemName in table, get sales data from `wp_quantum_sales`, else if ItemName exists in `wp_hunter_quote_parts` get data from `hunter_quote_parts` instead.

How can I combine first and second table, than do an outer join on it with another table?

Another Attempt here:

```
(SELECT IFNULL(qp.ItemName, qs.ItemName) AS name, IFNULL(qp.TimeAdded, qs.TimeAdded) AS created, qs.SalesDate AS effective, qp.VendorName AS supplier, qp.Source AS source, qp.VendorType AS type, qp.Price AS cost, qs.Price AS price, CAST((((CAST(qs.Price AS DECIMAL(10,2)) - CAST(qp.Price AS DECIMAL(10,2))) / CAST(qp.Price AS DECIMAL(10,2))) * 100) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS markup, qs.CustomerName AS customer, qs.CustomerListID AS customerListID, qp.VendorListID AS vendorListID, '' AS itemListID
                    FROM wp_quantum_purchases AS qp, wp_quantum_sales AS qs
                    WHERE (qp.IsActive = 1 OR qs.IsActive = 1)
            AND NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM wp_hunter_quote_parts AS hqp
                WHERE (qp.ItemName = hqp.ItemName || qs.ItemName = hqp.ItemName) AND hqp.IsActive = 1
            )
                )
                UNION ALL 
            (SELECT hqp.ItemName AS name, hq.Quote_Date AS created, hqp.SalesDate AS effective, hqp.VendorName AS supplier, hqp.Source AS source, hqp.VendorType AS type, hqp.Cost AS cost, hqp.Price AS price, CAST((((CAST(hqp.Price AS DECIMAL(10,2)) - CAST(hqp.Cost AS DECIMAL(10,2))) / CAST(hqp.Cost AS DECIMAL(10,2))) * 100) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS markup, IFNULL(hq.Customer_FullName, 'N/A') AS customer, hq.Customer_ListID AS customerListID, hqp.VendorListID AS vendorListID, hqp.Item_ListID AS itemListID
                    FROM wp_hunter_quote_parts AS hqp
                    LEFT JOIN wp_hunter_quotes AS hq ON (hq.id = hqp.QuoteID)
                    WHERE (hqp.IsActive = 1))
            ORDER BY name ASC
```

Figured this one would work, but seems that it just keeps going and going and going, and doesn't seem to ever finish the query.  No errors that I can see, but doesn't finish ever...  And these tables are very small, that is odd...

Answer (score 0):

I may not be understanding your question fully, but you could create a view of the first two tables and then do an outer join with the third table.

Comment: Not sure what creating a view does.  Basically, I need to combine first 2 tables as 1, than do an outer join on the last table.  If the last table has IsActive = 1 where ItemName is found, I need it to return that tables data instead.  Make sense?